# Turn off the roomba for child meta sites

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, per-site-meta, abandonment

Automatic deletion is useful and great on main sites, but on child metas it deletes my negatively voted feature-requests. >:(

Can it be turned off for child metas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a seemingly-endless number of bad ideas; we don't really need to archive them.

Of course... If someone writes up a really good explanation for *why* an idea is bad, that can be worth keeping around.

So if you see a meta question you don't want lost, write a good answer to it.

Comment: Meh. They'll just be duplicated. It doesn't cause any harm if it's so useless that nobody bumps it…

Comment: Yup, and there is even a [shiny gold badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/41/reversal) encouraging exactly this.

Comment: Can it at least be not rerumba'd when it was rumba'd then undeleted?

Comment: Absolutely, @bjb568! ...If you answer it after undeleting it, that is.

Comment: Now if I could find that question about vote confidence so I could add an answer…

Comment: Can this please [be reconsidered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322614/should-the-removedeadquestions-roomba-criterion-be-curtailed-on-meta-sites?noredirect=1)? This can result in perfectly reasonable posts getting deleted, such as arcane bug reports and controversial discussions. Another employee once upvoted such a question at the same time as undeleting it because of this behavior.

Comment: A very minor cosmetic bug in a browser we're not going to be able to support much longer doesn't strike me as worth spending time on, @sonic. Maybe I'm wrong, but nothing in your report suggests otherwise. For next time, I recommend referring to this guide when reporting bugs that you want to see fixed: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1920/best-guidelines-for-bug-reporting/1930#1930

Comment: @Shog9 How about the other discussion I linked there? The one that was undeleted *and upvoted* by Tim Post in order to bypass the deletion criteria on a valid question?

Comment: The discussion that, in the nearly three months since it was undeleted, has yet to attract any answers, any comments, any votes... Anything even remotely similar to a "discussion"? I donno, @Sonic... I think you can figure that one out for yourself.

Comment: @Shog9 It hasn't been bumped in the time after the undeletion, so it's natural that it hasn't received any attention yet. (I deleted my prior comment since I realized you were referring to the time after the undeletion.)