# Should Roomba have customized rules for meta websites?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, per-site-meta

Roomba, i.e. the system that takes care of automatically deleting supposedly low quality questions, is used in both main sites and meta sites. However, in meta sites, the voting system is different: people may downvote questions when in disagreement with the standpoint presented in the questions, despite the questions be of interest. But Roomba automatically deletes downvoted questions (with a few more criteria). Should Roomba have customized rules for meta websites, since the voting system is different?

---

For example, we could remove the Roomba's criteria on downvotes. Example of useful meta questions that it would save: https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2679/12

[image]

Comment: There is a similar [status-declined] [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238858/turn-off-the-roomba-for-child-meta-sites)

Comment: @rene thanks, I see, 30 upvotes, 4 downvotes, and declined. Typical.

Comment: I ran this [quick query](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/527112) because I assumed that the deletion percentage on meta would be lower but that is not the case (between MSO and SO)

Comment: @rene Interesting! Is there any way to filter by deletion reason?

Comment: Deletions don't have reasons.

Comment: @AlE. That's a pity, a lot of insight is lost there.

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of closures?

Comment: @AlE. No, deletion. Possible reason could be deletion by owner, admin, roomba.

Comment: I played a bit with [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/527114#graph). It shows ~time (hours * 100 + minutes). Roomba runs at 03:00 and you can see the spike there. Approx 383 (97 + 31) are deleted by roomba on MSO. The query does show a lot of spikes after midnight, I'm not sure if those also occur because of some script.

Comment: Without specific rules (and ideally examples of useful stuff they'd save), this is identical to the previous request.

Comment: @Shog9 added, please reopen, but typically discussions then focus on the example and not the main idea.

Comment: I addressed the main idea last time. So yeah, if I reopen, I'm going to focus on your example. If that's not what you want, let me know now so I don't bother reopening...

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if the problem is serious enough to warrant different rules.

Here are the times when posts get deleted for a couple of meta's with the number of posts deleted, from [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.superuser/query/527449#graph)

[image]

You can see the spikes when the Rooomba script runs:

- midnight for the 30 and 365 days old ([RemoveDeadQuestions and RemoveAbandonedQuestions](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5200363#5200363))
- 03:00 the 9-days old closed questions.

Based on these results I won't say that there is an unhealthy amount of posts deleted by the scripts.

In SEDE the table postswithdeleted doesn't contain taginfo for deleted posts but maybe a CM can give some insight in how many roomba deletes there are per tag on meta sites.

I have also run [this query for a few sites](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/527112) and the percentage for deleted posts is not alarmning.

If valuable but down voted posts run the risk of being deleted maybe that community can rewrite those posts in to FAQ posts. That keeps the value around while the roomba can still do its work.

Answer (score 3):

## Yes

For instance, [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s are likely to be heavily downvoted just because they're not viable as a feature. Deleting such posts would prevent them from being examples of what does the community dislike.

Comment: Most bad feature requests get an answer, that will be upvoted and with that prevents deletion, no matter how many downvotes are casted on the question

Comment: @rene Most but no all, especially when meta aren't that active, it's easy to get one downvote and no answer for 30 days.