# Why is the script for deletion called Roomba?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, auto-delete, terminology

In many posts I see that the script for automatic post deletion is called Roomba:

- [Turn off the roomba for child meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238858)
- [Turbocharging the Roomba: solutions for premature deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513)
- [Lost 5 questions following a serial downvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269392/)
- etc...

But I can’t find the origin of the name Roomba. 
Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: This should probably be included in the [meme list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19478/289905).

Comment: @Xufox Does anyone know when the Roomba was first mentioned?

Comment: @Xufox I added an entry for Roomba. Feel free to contribute! https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314070/394996

Comment: @chris The earliest mention I could find was Mar 25 '13 at 22:37 [Turbocharging the Roomba: solutions for premature deletion](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/173513)

Comment: I got my first Roomba when I was living in France ~7 years ago. [Roomba was the first commercially successful autonomous robotic vacuum cleaner easily available to the public](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Robotic_vacuum_cleaner&oldid=851254678): "The Roomba wasn’t the first robot vacuum, but it was the most successful.".  This help explain why "Roomba" was chosen and not some other autonomous robotic vacuum cleaner.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

A *[Roomba](https://www.irobot.co.uk)* is a brand of automatic robotic vacuum cleaner for cleaning floors.

The first robotic vacuum cleaner was the [Electrolux Trilobite in 2001](http://fortune.com/2013/11/29/the-history-of-the-roomba/). The iRobot Roomba was released in 2002. Many brands are now available, but it is the Roomba that most people associate with robotic vacuum cleaners (in the same way the brand Hoover became associated with standard vacuum cleaners in the past.

[image: Roomba]

Image taken from the [Wikipedia Roomba page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roomba).

The implication is that the post deletion script functions by itself in the background, so sometimes users will find posts have been deleted when they *return home*, much like the way in which a robotic vacuum cleaner will clean your house while you are away.

---

It’s probably important to point out that [XKCD](https://xkcd.com) loves Roombas!

[image: XKCD 1558 - Vet]

---

Another consideration (with thanks to [Mari-Lou A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/223820/mari-lou-a)) is that the word *Roomba* is a [play on words](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_play). [Rumba](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumba) is a style of music and type of dance. The robotic vacuum cleaner also *dances* and *sweeps* across the room, hence roomba. Similarly the Stack Exchange Roomba sweeps data away.

Comment: I think this fails to explain that the term is only known in North America (due to the market for robotic vacuum cleaners there?). And why "Roomba" has presumably become a synonym in North America for an automatic robotic vacuum cleaner. Like *[xerox](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/xerox#Noun)* vs. *[photocopier](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/photocopier)*.

Comment: If it has become a (local) common noun shouldn't it be spelled  *"roomba"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen While they originated in North America, Roomba’s are fairly well known here in the UK and certainly available to purchase online and in stores. I believe it’s similar in most of Europe. Other brands are available (Dyson have a notable one). Good point regarding common noun usage. Roomba did for robotic vacuum cleaners what Hoover did for standard vacuum cleaners!

Comment: @Chris Automatic vacuum cleaners might be very much ubiquitous on Earth, but his point was about the specific name that has a less global circulation.

Comment: @ChristianRau I had forgotten about this post! Thanks for your comment. How can I improve the answer? I’ve just done an edit linking to the Roomba product page.

Comment: I'd say it's a clever play on words *rumba* is a type of dance, and the automatic cleaner "dances/sweeps" across the *room* = ***room**ba* Ergo the SE Roomba sweeps data away.

Comment: @PeterMortensen - Roomba is a trademarked name. The only company that manufactures them is iRobot. The same way the others, Xerox, Kleenex, etc, would all like to keep their name. You know, aspirin used to be a trademarked name as well?

Comment: Roomba is certainly known outside of North America, though it may not have entered the popular consciousness to the same degree. Japan accounts for [a quarter of worldside Roomba sales](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AB%E3%83%B3%E3%83%90_(%E6%8E%83%E9%99%A4%E6%A9%9F)#%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E3%81%A8%E3%83%AB%E3%83%B3%E3%83%90).

Comment: So, essentially, it's an **EPONYM**.