# All of my suggested edits are being removed

Tags: discussion, edits, questions, suggested-edits

What is the point of being able to edit a question now, if any and all edits are removed by the question owner?

Most edits will get refused just from an ego standpoint.

With the new 'Reject Edit' option, I feel I'm wasting my time. I'm like a dog running after his tail.

[image: Screenshot of 7 edits showed "Removed" 9 hours ago in reputation history]

Should we even bother ?

Comment: You're hunting for easy reputation; It comes with a risk. You really have nothing to complain about.

Comment: You may want to concentrate the effort where it really matters - on [content with the highest impact](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/120907) (highest views per time unit (search engine hits)). Perhaps focused [in a specific tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/164178). (Don't worry - unlike most other sites, with 8,000 new questions per day on Stack Overflow ([20,799,893 question total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)), bumping is a total non-issue.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Nobody refused your edits, they are still there. The question owners have done nothing at all here.

What actually happened is that the questions you've been editing are being automatically deleted since even with your edit they are still poor quality questions.

When a post is deleted any increase (or decrease) in reputation you got from that post is removed as the post no longer contributes to helping anyone and also to try to encourage people to work on salvageable posts rather than unsalvageable ones.

If the questions you see are poor, downvote them and/or vote/flag them for closure unless you can fix them not to be poor.

In addition you're not really editing the questions to improve them you're just retagging them. Retagging can be useful but you need to fix the whole question if it needs an edit and remember not to bother if you're not going to end up making the question both on-topic and useful.

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65522838/how-can-i-replace-these-php-codes-without-receive-syntax-error) is a duplicate, it was downvoted and deleted by [the roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314065/why-is-the-script-for-deletion-called-roomba)
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65536160/aws-architecture-case-study-implementation-insight) was simply downvoted by three people and then directly deleted by the roomba. Not sure why you thought it worth your attention.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65537547/google-search-results-showup) was also downvoted and deleted by the roomba. It has the following comment under it

  > This question is about SEO which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read "Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?" to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance. Next time, please heed the warning and avoid asking non-programming related SEO related questions here.

  there really is no way to save that question by editing it.
- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65547307/parent-child-linking-with-shortcode-wordpress) you did try to improve the question but what does

  > Any help will be much appreciated.

  add? Why leave that in, it's just fluff. There's also a link to an image you could have inlined and worst of all no code, just a description of what they have coded, you really can't fix that ommission.

Comment: Ok I get that, but what is the point of having an edit verification process if, when the question is deleted the editor get sanctioned. Seing this just gives me no real motivation. I mostly hang out in the Wordpress tag on SO, and without tag editing our feed would be crowed with irrelevant question.

Comment: You didn't get sanctioned. You ended up the same as you started. Sanctions would mean you ended up worse off but X + 2 - 2 = X. If the questions you see are poor downvote them and/or vote/flag them for closue unless you can fix them not to be poor. Retagging questions doesn't fix them, it just leaves a bad question with fewer tags, you're not removing the trash, just moving it elsewhere and that has little value.

Comment: Well it's still a saction, you spend time, you get a reward, and 2 weeks latern, the reward is taken away. Closing question doesn't remove it from the feed, and the feed becomes unreadable. Retaging does, you point the toward the right tag.

Comment: you're trying to put lipstick on a pig with these questions. Best not to. Then you won't waste your time and everyone will be happier. Retagging removes it from **your** feed not from others who look at other tags which still show those questions.

Comment: I like the analogy. You're probably right still tho, retaging shouldn't even be an option then, if it's not welcome. We wouldn't be in this situation.

Comment: It's up to humans to decide here, there are plently of good quality questions with one bad tag and we need to be able to fix those.

Comment: That the posts were deleted was information I wouldn't have as a non 10k SO user *but* - considering that the suggested edit system is meant to teach folks how to edit effectively, wouldn't the 'negative reinforcement' of rep loss due to deleted questions essentially... kinda mean that the system is teaching you not to edit questions likely to be deleted?

Comment: @amarinediary retagging is good and acceptable. But the first thing to check is does the question fit the site's rules. If it does not the first thing to do is try to improve it so it does (but in most cases the questions are just bad and just flag thenm and don't waste time)

Comment: @amarinediary - If you don't want to be "sanctioned" just stop editing questions that should be deleted instead of edited. If the only thing you are doing is adding a tag to a question, you are probably not improving the question or making it easier to find, you probably need to also improve the quality of the question.  I rarely see edit proposals where a tag is added by itself is the only thing that could have been done.  Your edit makes the question appears on the front page, which means it draws attention away, from questions that could be answered. Simply retagging rarely alone is helpful

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the question owners removed those questions themselves. Rather, they were low quality questions which got cleaned up by [an automated process](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba). Apparently, even your edits weren't enough to put them in a shape where they were worth keeping. You can avoid this by concentrating your edits on answers, or questions which *do* have the potential to become decent questions.

(Also, try to fix *all* issues when editing a post; 'How can i replace these php codes without receive syntax error' could use a few grammar/capitalization corrections)

Answer (score 1):

Copy-editing and retagging is a valuable action for the site and gaining the +2 reputation is a fair reward both for improving post quality, discoverability, and encouraging the editor to become a proficient author who's able to write a flawlessly formatted post.

Part of a copy-editors broader skill is learning to recognize which posts will be deleted in the short term, some of those posts are not worth editing. This entails reasonably understanding the criteria that leads some posts to be [vote-closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) and deleted by the [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba).

A good strategy is editing older, open, up voted posts because they have a lower probability of being deleted. Also notice that if your edit was visible for at least 3 months you will keep the reputation gained from the edit even if the post is deleted.

Comment: Well i don't really agree, beside the +2 without retaging you would end up with crowed tag feed with unrelevant question, see the Wordpress tag, without retaging the feed is just unreadable.

Comment: Retaging is a way to filter, relevant question, "Hey that question don't belong here, let me point you to the right direction". The option shouldn't even exist if it's not welcome.

Comment: @amarinediary etagging still leaves a bad question as a bad question. Sure you don't see it if you're only looking at that tag but everyone else does so you're not eally helping the site as a whole The system would like to encourage you to do other things that will help instead.

Comment: One bad apple shouldn't define a group behaviour. But I get it. Sadly I really think that is a problem. At the end of the day, the frustration is still here, mostly when you try genuinely to get involved in the community; It's not really motivating.

Comment: @amarinediary - Why can't you add tags and perform other helpful improvements to a contribution?  Why do you feel unmotivated because your tag suggestions were not approved?