# Are manually undeleted questions eligible to auto deletion by roomba script again if other deletion conditions not changed?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, undelete, auto-delete

I have questions (the recent one [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395549/339911)) that has been deleted by [Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314065/339911). I'm curious will these questions be eligible to auto deletion again if they will be undeleted manually by users? Will be there some other behavior if they will be undeleted by mods?

Comment: TL;DR yes, they might get deleted again, there are pending (?) feature requests asking to change it.